# Reading scheduled posts via Graph API /feed

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to pull **scheduled** posts via Graph api using [/feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/) method

I don't think there is, but I wanted to ask.